# running configuration check on service restart

Tags: xubuntu

I have ubuntu 14 on 1 server and when I restart a service, it does a running configuration check. On my other server I have ubuntu 16 and it doesn't do this when I restart a service. Any idea why? see below on the output when I restart a nagios service.

> sysadmin@nagios:~$ sudo service nagios restart
>   Running configuration check...
>   Stopping nagios:. done.
>   Starting nagios: done.

Comment: The packages for `nagios` are different. Look at `/etc/init/nagios` on both machines.

Comment: @waltinator I am guessing is suggesting that this is normal with more recent versions of nagios due to changes in start (init) scripts. I am not sure but you can check this by reviewing the scripts if you wish.